# How can I get Location of a DiscoveryResult when executing search suggestion?

Tags: here-api

I'm using android SDK implement the search suggestion, code looks like below:

```
 private void performSearch(CharSequence searchTerm) {
    try {
        DiscoveryRequest request = new SearchRequest( searchTerm.toString())
                .setSearchCenter( mMap.getCenter() )
                .setCollectionSize( 10 );
        ErrorCode error = request.execute( mSearchRequestListener );
        if ( error != ErrorCode.NONE ) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Here API place search error: " + error.name() );
            mSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    } catch ( IllegalArgumentException ex ) {
        Log.i( TAG, "Here API place search exception: " +
                ex.getMessage() != null ? ex.getMessage() : "" );
        mSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}

private ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage> mSearchRequestListener =
        new ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage data, ErrorCode error) {
        if ( error != ErrorCode.NONE ) {
            Log.i( TAG, "Here API place search error: " + error.name() );
            mSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "mSearchRequestListener.onCompleted: count=" + data.getItems().size() );
        mResultList = new ArrayList<DiscoveryResult>( data.getItems());
        String vicinity = mResultList.get(0).getVicinity();
        //String location = ?
        mSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

How can I get the Location of a DiscoveryResult after I get DiscoveryResult list? It seems I didn't find this property in DiscoveryResult object. I need to add this location to my RoutePlan to calculate a route.

```
RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();
routePlan.addWaypoint(currentGeoCoordinate);
routePlan.addWaypoint(destGeoCoordinate);
routeManager.calculateRoute( routePlan, mRouteManagerListener );
```

I have a workaround for this in my code. After I get vicinity, I make a request at http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=" +  vicinity + "gen=9"; to get the response. There is a Location property in response of this request. the disadvantage is I need to make a request to get location every time. Any suggestion to get the location without making a request to server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found another workaround is:
ResultListener<List<com.here.android.mpa.search.Location>> searchListener = new GeocodeListener();
                String place = placePrediction.getVicinity().replace( "<br/>", ", " );
                GeocodeRequest request = new GeocodeRequest(place).setSearchArea(currentGeoCoordinate, 5000).setCollectionSize(1);
                request.execute(searchListener);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the DiscoveryResultPage can be of several types, and you should sheck for the right type.

See documentation here:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/places.html

The important part:

> Calling DiscoveryResultPage.getItems(), returns a List containing one
>   of the following types of objects, which are DiscoveryResult
>   instances. DiscoveryResult is a collection of Link subtypes.
>
> PlaceLink - Represents discovery information about a Place. The
>   PlaceLink contains a brief summary about a place. Details about a
>   place are available from the Place that the PlaceLink references.
>   DiscoveryLink - Represents a discovery-related API link used to
>   retrieve additional DiscoveryResultPage. This type of Link can be a
>   result item in an Explore or Here type of search. The DiscoveryLink
>   references refined discovery requests resulting in more specific
>   results. For example, the DiscoveryLink may link to a discovery
>   request to search for 'Eat & Drink', 'Going Out', 'Accommodation', and
>   so on. Since there may be new types of Link items in the future, it is
>   recommended that each type of DiscoveryResult be checked before it is
>   used (as shown in the following code snippet).

That means practically, that you iterate over data and check for the types like this:

```
// Implement a search result listener
ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage> searchListener = new ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage>() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage results, ErrorCode error) {

    if (error == ErrorCode.NONE) {
      // The results is a DiscoveryResultPage which represents a
      // paginated collection of items.
      List<DiscoveryResult> items = results.getItems();

      // Iterate through the found place items.
      for (DiscoveryResult item : items) {
        // A Item can either be a PlaceLink (meta information
        // about a Place) or a DiscoveryLink (which is a reference
        // to another refined search that is related to the
        // original search; for example, a search for
        // "Leisure & Outdoor").

        if (item.getResultType() == ResultType.PLACE) {
          PlaceLink placeLink = (PlaceLink) item;

          // PlaceLink should be presented to the user, so the link can be
          // selected in order to retrieve additional details about a place
          // of interest.
          ...

        } else if (item.getResultType() == ResultType.DISCOVERY) {
          DiscoveryLink discoveryLink = (DiscoveryLink) item;

          // DiscoveryLink can also be presented to the user.
          // When a DiscoveryLink is selected, another search request should be
          // performed to retrieve results for a specific category.
          ...
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Handle search request error.
    }
  }
};
```

or only get the PlaceLink items directly like that:

```
   public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage data, ErrorCode error) {
                List<PlaceLink> results = data.getPlaceLinks();  // we are only interested in PlaceLinks

                if (results.size() > 0) {                  
                    for (PlaceLink result : results) {
                           // do something with the PlaceLink item
                    }

                } else {
                    // handle empty result case
                }
```

The PlaceLink object then has all the methods you would except, also getPosition() or getDistance() that you can use for putting results on the map or calculate a route.